# Why does Assigning to a property throw a LazyInitializationException ("Proxy not found") in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Previously I posted a question for a solution on ****LazyIntialization exception: Proxy not found - Session was closed*** *. But later in my code I found that I am using load() method instead of get() method to retrive the entity object. So I changed the load() method to get() and it started working.

Below is the snippet of the code,

```
Answer answerObj = HibernateTemplate.load(Answer.class,1001); --> line 1

answerObj.setPoints(2990); --> line 2
```

when I run this it thrown the LazyInitialization exception:Proxy not found on line 2.

I understand that when I use load() method it returns me proxy object instead of the persistent row from database. So my Answer object has just the Id value and all other properties are empty.

Now in line 2 of the code I was trying to set one of the proxy object's (Answer) property to some value. Then why it is throwing the proxy not available exception? What is the wrong thing in assiging a value to the proxy object property?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not know if setting a property has logic (eg validation) which involves other properties as well and does the only safe thing loading the object from database before calling the real setter.